# Hibernate doesnt save entity when I refresh it

Tags: java, hibernate

I have an existing object that has different things changed in one transaction:

```
TX start
0) Load object by id 

      public MyModel load ( final Long objectId ) {
        return super.getHibernateTemplate().execute(new HibernateCallback<MyModel>() {
           public MyModel doInHibernate ( Session session ) throws HibernateException, SQLException {
                MyModel myModel =  (MyModel)session.load(MyModel.class, objectId);
               //optionally I do     session.refresh(myModel);
               return myModel;
            }
        });
    }
1) Change externalIdentifier  

public void setExternalIdentifier(Long objectId, Long externalIdentifier) {
        MyModel myModel = myDAO.loadMyModel(objectId, null);
        myModel.setExternalIdentifier(externalIdentifier);
    }

2) Change color
3) Change state
4) Dao.saveOrUpdate
TX end
```

Changes are persisted and it works fine. However, when I do 1) in newTx then in 2) I dont see externalIdentifier on object so I do load and refresh before 2). Unfortunatelly 2,3,4 doesnt not change anything in database althouhg I see changed fields on debug..

Problem occurs when I do setExternalIdentifier in newTx, then ExternalIdentifier is persisted in db immidiatelly but other changes like state and color are not.

Comment: Add some code, not just some steps ...

Answer (score 0):

By default, Hibernate uses the `AUTO` strategy for persisting your Data, with this option Hibernate will decide when he should persist to increase its performance, what you can do is change your `session` flush mode to `ALWAYS` like this:

`session.setFlushMode(FlushMode.ALWAYS);`

or you can force a `flush` like this:

`session.flush()`

It should work.